# No InnoDB found in database engines

Tags: mysql, innodb

I'm very new to MySQL. I want to configure MySQL on Windows. I've installed the server. While installing I chose non-transactional databases (not sure why).

After installation. Opened command prompt from bin folder. When I execute the following command

```
\bin>mysql -u root -p
```

it is showing error

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)

then I ran command

```
\bin>mysqld --skip-grant-tables &
```

(this seems like runnning. Doesn't come to new line).

Then I was able to connect.

```
\bin>mysql -u root -p
mysql>
```

(asked for password. entered)

When I try to query a table, it's giving out an error like

> Unknown Storage Engine 'innoDB'.

I ran command

```
show engines;
```

I don't see `InnoDB` at all for the queried databases.

Comment: Try to add these line to my.cnf

default-storage-engine=innodb 
default-table-type=innodb

Comment: Reinstall it with transactional engine support? You installed it **without InnoDB** and you wonder why there is no InnoDB. I mean really..

Comment: If this is a new setup, and it would seem so from the description, I would concur with N.B. to just reinstall the thing, easier all around.